# How to dynamically set API key in angular module

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-google-maps, angular-module

I want to set the google maps API key dynamically into the module so that when it loads up, it gets the correct key depending on each environment (like dev, QA or production). If anybody knows that or encountered a similar issue, that would be a great help!

Comment: what do you mean dynamically, do you want to change it in runtime, or it will be fixed and different for each environment

Comment: @Reza Dynamically means: setting a different value depending on environment.

Comment: and you don't want to change it when it's set, for example if on prod you set it to `val1` you don't want to change it (unless you build the application) correct?

Comment: @Reza correct, I wont change it.

Comment: then both below answers works for you

Comment: @Reza not really, actually both of these solutions are about reading the value from environment file. But in my case I’m getting it through a service call.

Comment: So if you are getting the key through a service call, it's already dynamic and you need to change the backend to handle that

Answer (score 2):

For this reason you have `environment.ts`, `environment.prod.ts` etc files in your `src/environments` folder. So your solution could look as follows.

1. Create appropriate `environment.<env>.ts` files in `src/environments` folder, i.e.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  GM_API_KEY: 'YOUR API KEY HERE',
  ...
};
```

2. In your `angular.json` file add appropriate configurations and set the file replacements

```
"configurations": {
    "prod": {...},
    "stage": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
            }
        ],
        ...
```

3. Import api keys from the environment

```
import {environment} from 'path/to/environment';

// environment.GM_API_KEY <= use api key where you need it
```

4. Build application for specific environment

```
ng build --configuration=stage
```

That's it. Please, let me know if something remains unclear for you or you need some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key in the environment file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:68888/api'
};
```

and import it in your service. Then your production key can be added in the .prod environment file. When you build for production add --configuration=production, this will switch out the base environment file with the .prod one. More detailed information can be found [here](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15) and [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8) including how to add more environments for QA and other production environments.